# jQuery smooth scrolling on single page site

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to apply a smooth scrolling effect to divs with numbered ids within a single page using jQuery. The function I made takes clicked anchors and tries to animate the body to scroll to them using the scrollTop jQuery function. Any ideas why this isn't working?

EDIT: The divs in question are set to height:100% and the anchor tags are all within fixed elements - would this interfere with the scrolling? (See edit at bottom)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


//grab any anchor, when clicked, with an id that isn't blank

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(){


//store the result and wrap it

    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var targetWrapped = $(target);


//call function scrollToDiv

    scrollToDiv(targetWrapped);
    return false;
});


//create scrollToDiv function that finds the offset of the 

function scrollToDiv(element){  

    var offset = element.offset();

    $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: offset
    }, 500);

}

});
</script>
```

EDIT:
The HTML of the divs is simply:

```
<div class="section fit" id="1">
</div>
<div class="section fit" id="2">
</div>
<div class="section fit" id="2">
</div>
```

The anchor tags look like this:

```
<div class="floatbox3">
  <a href="#2">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up glyph3" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Back"></span>
    <h2 class="direction">Back</h2>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="floatbox2">
  <a href="#4">
    <h2 class="direction">Next</h2>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down glyph3" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Next"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
.section {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.fit {
height: 100%;
}  

.floatbox2{
position:absolute;
right:50px;
bottom:400px;
height:150px;
width:150px;
}

.floatbox3{
position:absolute;
right:50px;
top:440px;
height:150px;
width:150px;
}
```

The position is relative because I have absolute navigation elements sitting on top.

Answer (score 2):

`element.offset()` contains both top and left offsets. You need to use `offset.top`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  //grab any anchor, when clicked, with an id that isn't blank
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function(){
    //store the result and wrap it
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    var targetWrapped = $(target);
    //call function scrollToDiv
    scrollToDiv(targetWrapped);
    return false;
  });

  //create scrollToDiv function that finds the offset of the 
  function scrollToDiv(element){  
    var offset = element.offset();
    $('body,html').animate({
      scrollTop: offset.top
    }, 500);
  }
  
});
```

```css
body { width: 600px; /* test purpose only */ }
.section { position: relative; width: 100%; }
.fit { height: 100%; }  
.floatbox2 { position:absolute; right:50px; bottom:400px; height:150px; width:150px; }
.floatbox3 { position:absolute; right:50px; top:440px; height:150px; width:150px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section fit" id="1">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <div class="floatbox2">
        <a href="#2"><h2 class="direction">Next</h2></a>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula.</p>
</div>
<div class="section fit" id="2">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <div class="floatbox3">
        <a href="#1"><h2 class="direction">Back</h2></a>
    </div>
    <div class="floatbox2">
        <a href="#3"><h2 class="direction">Next</h2></a>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula.</p>
</div>
<div class="section fit" id="3">
    <h1>3</h1>
    <div class="floatbox3">
        <a href="#2"><h2 class="direction">Back</h2></a>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. However, it still isn't working!

Comment: It works for elements within a div but not to go from div to div.

Comment: Can't understand your comment. Be more explicit, and provide us an HTML example (edit your question) for us to know where to look. Thanks.

Comment: okay, I have updated the code with more details. The target ids for scrolling belong to a series of divs representing full-screen-height sections of content - thanks.

Comment: @geoman I edited my post with your example to show you it perfectly works.

Comment: Any ideas what might stop it working then? I have too much code to paste it all here. Could there be anything inside the numbered divs that would interfere with its correct function?

Answer (score 1):

Use This one

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```